# OS specific PATH separator in Julia

Tags: julia

I couldn't find whether Julia provides the OS specific char to separate PATH-like strings, such as PATH=c:\windows\systems32;c:\windows;... and similar environment variables in Linux. OS specific because Windows is using ";" and Linux ":".  I neither could find a helper function that does the splitting already and just not exposing the separator char. But couldn't find that either.

It's easy enough to define these myself, I was only surprised not to find them.

thanks lot for your help

Answer (score 5):

No, there isn't a path list separator by default.  What you can do is

```
Sys.iswindows() ? ';' : ':'
```

Comment: It would be good to have an official exported name for this though so that it's easier to use.

Comment: Python has `os.path.sep` for this, but Julia uses `Filesystem.pathsep` (and `Filesystem.path_separator`) already for the path separator.  I'm not sure what could be a good name, without being too verbose: this is a "path _list_ separator", not just "path separator"

Comment: R is similar to Python: `.Platform$path.sep`